# clearing the symfony cache doesn't work

Tags: symfony, permissions

I want to clear the `cache`, but I got an error that `file is not writable`, so I choose to `delete` cache folder manually, but that too doesn't work.

I have all permissions to delete files but I didn't understand what's the problem.

Comment: the webserver is running under different user (for example www-data) and your console under differet (root, vagrant, whatever). When you delete the cache manually, webserver cannot write anything there anymore.

Comment: Make sure to change the permissions to writeable for the webserver after you remove the cache by hand.

Answer (score 0):

may be ACL can help you, try this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache
sudo setfacl -dR -m u::rwX app/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 doc has clear instructions how to setup your cache in proper way "Setting up Permissions" http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: thanks Evgeniy Kuzmin , i verified all permissions , i was the root but i can't delete the cache file

Comment: it show me" drwxrwxr-t  4 bli bli  4096 أبر 29 10:55 cache"